# Google Sheets LEFT and ISNUMBER - Starfleet HR

Tags: google-sheets

tl;dr - How can I pull the first two characters from a column and have a second column declare whether those characters are a numerical value (no text)?

sub-question: why doesn't `IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(C2,2)), "yes", "no")` do what I just said?

--

I'm a Starfleet HR Officer, and our database is a MESS. For a while there, the Vulcans were running our Humanoid Resources, and now our officer and crew tracking numbers have been...VULCANED.

[Starfleet Humanoid Resources Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzDvV-g-1atVeRcZscW9LMyNkesq4_DrKkuSOtI5gKo/edit?usp=sharing)

In that sample sheet, we have a Starfleet ID and a Vulcan High Command ID for each member of the bridge crew of the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701). That would be great, except that some of the Officers have both their SFID and their VHCID, and some have VHCID in both fields. I need to be able to flag one of the two kinds of IDs in the Starfleet ID column - the VHCID looks simpler.

I want to call something like `IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(C2,2)), "VHCID", "SFID")`, since ALL the VHCIDs start with two digits. But, as you can see, the sheet throws an SFID for all the `LEFT` output, even though, when I pull the two digits out, they are clearly numbers in some cases.

Anyone boldly gone here before?

Comment: Put the question in the question please. Not everyone can & wants to click through to a random google sheet. Also, why is this tagged [tag:excel] ?

Comment: @AakashM Does what you need?

Comment: Just want to thank anybody who's ever swung in here to look at this - it remains one of my favorite pieces of WRITING that I've ever done. 

I hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding a +0 after the Left() method will try and convert the result in to a number.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(B2,2)+0),"VHCID","SFID")
```

Seems to give the expected results.

As the comment points out, both Google Sheets and Excel has a function to convert the string to a text, called [Value()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en).  I had no idea that function existed in Excel, so thank you for sharing.  The formula using the Value() function would look something like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B2,2))),"VHCID","SFID")
```

Answer to your edit:

The function Left() is [expecting a string and returns a string](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079).  The function IsNumber() [just checks to see if the input is a number](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296).  Since the Left() function returns a string, it will **always** evaluate to false in the IsNumber() function.

To get around that, you can add 0 to the Left() function, which will convert the string to a number automagically (basically it will try to force the string to be a numeric to handle the mathematical operation).  If the result of the Left() function is something like "42", then adding 0 makes it 42, which resolves to 'true' in the IsNumber() function.  If your Left() function results in "Text", then the conversion fails, "Text" + 0 = "Text" and the IsNumber() function resolves to false.

**TLDR:** "42" and 42 are completely different things, adding 0 (or using the Value() function) fixes that.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That makes total sense. Having looked at your answer also explains why what I ended up finding that worked, worked:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B2,2))),"VHCID","SFID")`

That VALUE call there also "de-strings" the product of LEFT, so that ISNUMBER evaluates correctly. 

Thanks, @sous2817